# Set style of XFCE UI element knowing its class and property

Tags: themes, gtk3, xfce

In general, I would like to understand how to change the style of elements in the latest (gtk3) development versions of XFCE. But to keep the question focused I'm going to ask for a particular case: changing the icon size of the alt-tab window switcher.

The code is [here](https://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/tree/src/tabwin.c). One can see that a class is registered with name `XfwmTabwinWidget` and later a property `icon-size` for that class is added:

```
...
        type = g_type_register_static (GTK_TYPE_WINDOW, "XfwmTabwinWidget", &info, 0);
...
    gtk_widget_class_install_style_property (widget_class,
                                             g_param_spec_int ("icon-size",
                                                               "icon size",
                                                                "the size of the application icon",
                                                                24, 128,
                                                                WIN_ICON_SIZE,
                                                                G_PARAM_READABLE));
...
```

Now, my first (and only) attempt was to add the following to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```
XfwmTabwinWidget {
    icon-size: 128px;
}
```

But I get

```
(xfwm4:28535): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:35:08.156: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2:13: 'icon-size' is not a valid property name
```

Well, that was the example but, returning to the general case, how do I change the style of a property of some element once I have the relevant fragments of source code (as the ones above).

Answer (score 0):

Not that I understand it quite well but at least for my example I could get it as desired by adding this to my `gtk.css`:

```
* {
    -XfwmTabwinWidget-icon-size: 96;
}
```